# Is BAWSAQ down / under maintenance right now?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I am trying to access BAWSAQ and it keeps showing me an error. Is it currently under maintenance? Or am I doing something wrong? I am signed in to my PSN account.

Comment: What error is it showing? Can you include any other information?

Comment: ah man its saying market is down for maintenance. any idea how long this goes on? i am in the thick of it :/ and id like to invest

Comment: @Frank yes maybe but i wanted an updated answer. Also, just for information for other peeps checking the comments, i was not able to login to BAWSAQ even though the link gauzy posted shows the server is up and running. probably try again tomorrow. Im in Thailand and its about 3.30am.

Comment: @akshat Arqade works differently than most sites; we don't allow questions asking the same thing just for an updated answer.  If you want updated answers, our policy is to leave a comment requesting an update, or bountying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rockstar has a [support page about this error](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200222867--Down-for-Maintenance-error-on-GTA-V-s-BAWSAQ-stock-market). From there, I was also able to follow some links to arrive at this [GTA Online Status](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200426246) page, which states that PS3's status is UP as of February 10. Might be worth keeping an eye on that page to see if this is an ongoing outage with an estimated recovery time or just a temporary hiccup.

Comment: @akshat No problem - if this answers your question, feel free to mark this answer as "Accepted" so that others can benefit from seeing the solution as well.